# What would happen if you made a horcrux after taking the fidelius charm?

Tags: harry-potter, fidelius-charm

I was reading this question, [Would Voldemort's Taboo Spell Trump the Fidelius Charm?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/24881/3804), and I thought to myself if the secret is kept in the soul, what happens if it's split?

> ‘An immensely complex spell,’ he said squeakily, ‘involving the magical concealment of a secret inside a single, living soul. The information is hidden inside the chosen person, or Secret-Keeper, and is henceforth impossible to find – unless, of course, the Secret-Keeper chooses to divulge it. As long as the Secret-Keeper refused to speak, You-Know-Who could search the village where Lily and James were staying for years and never find them, not even if he had his nose pressed against their sitting-room window!’
>   <sub>*Prisoner of Azkaban* - pages 152-153 - Bloomsbury - chapter 10, *The Marauders Map*</sub>

What happens if that soul then becomes lodged in someone or somethign else? Could the secret be found out that way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know that the Horcrux pieces are able to communicate (diary, locket talking to Ron, Nagini communicating to both Voldemort and Harry in parseltongue), so they can definitely reveal their copy/clone of the secret *if they know that secret*.

---

NOTE: It may be speculated that the secret can only reside with ONE of the pieces of soul (presumably, the main one), but there's no canon proof for or against that, and it makes less sense from cryptographic point of view. You can have 2 nodes that know the private key.

Comment: Actually there is canon proof **against** the secret needing to reside in only ONE soul. When Dumbledore dies the secret then resided in all of the people whom he told it to. +1