# How is the use of Voldemort's name justified in Grimmauld's place?

Tags: harry-potter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Would Voldemort’s Taboo Spell Trump the Fidelius Charm?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24881/would-voldemorts-taboo-spell-trump-the-fidelius-charm)

In Harry Potter and The Deathly Hallows,the Voldemort's name is "taboed".That is how Harry,Ron and Hermione suffer an attack from death-eaters in Tottenham Court Road,soon after they disapparate from the wedding.But then,during their stay in Grimmauld's place, they use Voldemort's name many times casually,then why doesn't anything happen then?..I know that the obvious answer would be that Moody would have placed protective enchantments over the place,but then when they get caught while camping in the forest(after Harry accidently using Voldemort's name) ,they did have protective enchantments themselves,didn't they?..Then how is the use in Grimmauld place justified?..Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to suggest No twelve Grimmauld is under the Fidelius Charm:

> Tall, dilapidated houses looked down on them from every side. **Number twelve was visible to them, for they had been told of its existence by Dumbledore, its Secret Keeper**, and they rushed towards it, checking every few yards that they were not being followed or observed. They raced up the stone steps and Harry tapped the front door once, with his wand. They heard a series of metallic clicks and the clatter of a chain, then the door swung open with a creak and they hurried over the threshold.
>   <sub>*Deathly Hallows* - page 141 - Bloomsbury - chapter 9, *A Place to Hide*</sub>

When Harry, Ron, or Hermione -- who at this point know nothing about Voldemort's name carrying a taboo -- say Voldemort's name, the Death Eaters are drawn to the house, but the Fidelius Charm apparently keeps them from gaining access to the inside of the house. One of the other reasons the Death Eaters are there in the first place is that it's public record that Sirius left Grimmauld Place to Harry, so Grimmauld is merely a logical place to place under surveillance. Grimmauld is somehow protected from the Death Eaters and they cannot see its occupants. This is why the trio and Lupin have to take such extreme care and Apparate directly onto the top step leading into Grimmauld. Otherwise they are visible and vulnerable to capture.

Comment: @A Slytherin : Why can't the death eaters' gain access?..After all,Snape is also one who is aware of the place,so he might as well made it known to them,after Dumbledore's death..And as you say Grimmauld's place is merely a logical place to place under surveillance..so they might not have really been there because of the taboo..in your opinion is Fidelius charm more powerful than the taboo?..If so,how could Voldemort and the death-eaters have missed it while using the taboo?

Comment: Snape was not able to tell anyone the secret about Grimmauld because he was cursed by Moody's tongue-tying curse, which wouldn't allow him to speak of what he knew about Grimmauld. The Death Eaters cannot gain access because they have not been told the secret. And, as Prof. Flitwick says in *Prisoner of Azkaban*, 'You-Know-Who could search the village where Lily and James were staying for years and never find them, not even if he had his nose pressed against their sitting-room window!’ That's just how the Fidelius Charm works. And, yes, Fidelius *appears* to be more powerful than the taboo.

Comment: And I'm not sure what you mean by your last sentence about Voldemort and the Death Eaters missing something while using the taboo, but I can only speak to questions that have a definitive answer; subjective answers, or guesses, are discouraged here. I have no idea why Voldemort missed whatever-it-was while using the taboo.

Comment: When I say Voldemort and the Death Eaters missing something while using the taboo, I mean if taboo could have been fooled by Fidelius charm,then every wizard who had gone into hiding could have used it and the taboo would never have had it's effect.But then,I agree with u when u say Fidelius appears to be more powerful than the taboo,otherwise Dumbledore would not have trusted Fidelius charm to be used by Lily and James.

Comment: It is, yes. But Remus pointed out that they were all over the place and so there might not be any connexion to the taboo at all.